# Magento 2: Price format is wrong in Indian Rupees?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.3, currency

I am using `Magento 2.2.3`  with my default currency is INR but its show in wrong format.

[image]

[image]

But it should be ₹77,65,000.00, how we correct price format currently its working like USD.

I have tried many ways but I am not able to resolve this please help to resolve this issue.